# Existence of nonfaithful tracial states in infinite von Neumann algebra

Tags: operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

Can there exist non faithful tracial state in infinite von Neumann algebras ? As faithfulness plays the role to show the vN algebra has to be finite. Further are all hyperfinite $II_{1}$ factors are all classified upto isomorphism? How one can show hyperfinite $II_{1}$ factor is embedded in any $II_{1}$  factor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take any von Neumann algebra $N$ with a trace $\tau_0$, let $M=N\oplus N$, and define
$$
\tau(x\oplus y)=\tau_0(x). 
$$

For your second question, there is a single hyperfinite II$_1$-factor, so there is nothing to classify.

For your third question, the answer is [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2196583/22857) (you should search at least a little before asking!).

Comment: Okk, thanks.. I will definitely search before asking